# Installing Ubuntu on VirtualBox from iso

Tags: macos, ubuntu, windows-xp, virtualbox

I'm having some trouble. I have VirtualBox installed on both a OS X Lion Macbook Pro and a Windows XP Lenovo Laptop, and they both behave the same way. I've downloaded Ubuntu as an .iso from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

I set up the virtual machine and everything looks great, but when it gets to boot time it just sits there with a black screen and blinking prompt. The file command on the iso says it's a bootable image, so I'm n

[image: Ubuntu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you boot the Ubuntu CD, you will first see this screen:

[image: Ubuntu 12.04 Boot Screen]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you see this screen. You will then get the Ubuntu boot menu where you can choose a language and boot options.

Select your language, then press <kbd>F6</kbd> for boot options. Use your arrow keys to select `nomodeset` so that an `x` appears next to it.

[image: Ubuntu 12.04 Boot Screen with nomodeset selected]

Then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Now, use your arrow keys to scroll down to Install Ubuntu, and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Comment: I am able to access those menus, but after selecting Install Ubuntu it sits at the _ prompt again.

Comment: It basically came down to the fact that the iso I had was bad. I downloaded a fresh one and now it's installing just fine